# communication between Python 3 and Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

What is the best way to communicate between a Python 3.x and a Python 2.x program?

We're writing a web app whose front end servers will be written in Python 3 (CherryPy + uWSGI) primarily because it is unicode heavy app and Python 3.x has a cleaner support for unicode.

But we need to use systems like Redis and Boto (AWS client) which don't yet have Python 3 support.

Hence we need to create a system in which we can communicate between Python 3.x and 2.x programs.

What do you think is the best way to do this?

Comment: Not constructive? These are often exactly the sort of questions we need answers to. Here is an excellent post that hasn't been over policed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334302/communication-between-two-separate-python-engines

Answer (score 2):

The best way? Write everything in Python 2.x. It's a simple question: can I do everything in Python 2.x? Yes! Can I do everything in Python 3.x? No. What's your problem then?

But if you really, really have to use two different Python versions ( why not two different languages for example? ) then you will probably have to create two different servers ( which will be clients at the same time ) which will communicate via TCP/UDP or whatever protocol you want. This might actually be quite handy if you think about scaling the application in the future. Although let me warn you: it won't be easy at all.

Comment: Yes, I am thinking exactly on these lines. But what's the communication medium I should use? MessagePack? or something else?

Comment: Why won't it be easy? Designing a small rpc protocol in xml can be done in under 100 loc as long as you don't have special requirements...

Comment: @l4mpi Yeah, designing might be easy. However there are a lot of subtleties like making it fault tolerant, queueing requests/responses, caching ( if needed ), etc. etc. I'm not saying that it is extremely difficult, it's just that you need to be aware of such things and be more careful than usual.

Comment: @good_computer It depends on your situation. Most of the time I would go for JSON to be honest. MessagePack looks good, though ( didn't know it before ).

Comment: How about JSON and HTTP? Very easy to use protocol.

Comment: @LennartRegebro There are some disadvantages of HTTP: you have to recreate request every time you want data but opening and closing HTTP connections eats resources and also you pass some additional ( and unnecessary ) data on each request/response ( for example headers ). So I don't think it suitable for this kind of task. As I said: I would use JSON with UDP or TCP. UDP is faster, but less reliable, so it actually depends what kind of data OP is dealing with and how important it is.

Comment: Ah, yes, in the comments you wrote JSON, I didn't see that. JSON + TCP works if he needs to do a lot of small transfers, sure. Going from TCP  to UDP because of efficiency is almost always a mistake.